# VB.net httpwebrequest For loop hangs every 10 or so iterations

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to loop through an array and perform an httpwebrequest in each iteration.
The code seems to work, however it pauses for a while (eg alot longer than the set timeout. Tried setting that to 100 to check and it still pauses) after every 10 or so iterations, then carries on working.

Here is what i have so far:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfProxies - 1

            Try
                'create request to a proxyJudge php page using proxy
                Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.pr0.net/deny/azenv.php")
                request.Proxy = New Net.WebProxy(proxies(i)) 'select the current proxie from the proxies array
                request.Timeout = 10000 'set timeout 

                Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

                Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Dim pageSourceCode As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
                'check the downloaded source for certain phrases, each identifies a type of proxy
                'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR identifies a transparent proxy
                If pageSourceCode.Contains("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") Then
                    'delegate method for cross thread safe
                    UpdateListbox(ListBox3, proxies(i))
                ElseIf pageSourceCode.Contains("HTTP_VIA") Then
                    UpdateListbox(ListBox2, proxies(i))
                Else
                    UpdateListbox(ListBox1, proxies(i))
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString) used in testing
                UpdateListbox(ListBox4, proxies(i))
            End Try
            completedProxyCheck += 1
            lblTotalProxiesChecked.CustomInvoke(Sub(l) l.Text = completedProxyCheck)

        Next
```

I have searched all over this site and via google, and most responses to this type of question say the response must be closed. I have tried a using block, eg:

```
Using response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim pageSourceCode As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
                    'check the downloaded source for certain phrases, each identifies a type of proxy
                    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR identifies a transparent proxy
                    If pageSourceCode.Contains("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") Then
                        'delegate method for cross thread safe
                        UpdateListbox(ListBox3, proxies(i))
                    ElseIf pageSourceCode.Contains("HTTP_VIA") Then
                        UpdateListbox(ListBox2, proxies(i))
                    Else
                        UpdateListbox(ListBox1, proxies(i))
                    End If
End Using
End Using
```

And it makes no difference (though i may have implemented it wrong) As you can tell im very new to VB or any OOP so its probably a simple problem but i cant work it out.

Any suggestions or just tips on how to diagnose these types of problems would be really appreciated.

EDIT:
Now im thoroughly confused. Does the try catch statement automatically close the response, or do i need to put something in Finally? If so, what? i cant use response.close() because its declared in the try block.

Perhaps im just using really badly structured code and there is a much better way to do this? Or something else is causing the pause/hang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, it's a very difficult to write code in comment I will continue as answer.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfProxies - 1
Dim response As HttpWebResponse
    Try
        'create request to a proxyJudge php page using proxy
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.pr0.net/deny/azenv.php")
        request.Proxy = New Net.WebProxy(proxies(i)) 'select the current proxie from the proxies array
        request.Timeout = 10000 'set timeout 

        response = request.GetResponse()

        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim pageSourceCode As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
        'check the downloaded source for certain phrases, each identifies a type of proxy
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR identifies a transparent proxy
        If pageSourceCode.Contains("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") Then
             'delegate method for cross thread safe
              UpdateListbox(ListBox3, proxies(i))
        ElseIf pageSourceCode.Contains("HTTP_VIA") Then
              UpdateListbox(ListBox2, proxies(i))
        Else
              UpdateListbox(ListBox1, proxies(i))
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString) used in testing
        UpdateListbox(ListBox4, proxies(i))
    Finally
        response.Close()
    End Try
    completedProxyCheck += 1
    lblTotalProxiesChecked.CustomInvoke(Sub(l) l.Text = completedProxyCheck)

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you need to close the response after you are done with it, as .net enforces a maximum number of concurrent requests

so just add

```
response.close()
```

at the end of your code block

Comment: It is not a deal here, regarding to second block of code: "A Using block behaves like a Try...Finally construction in which the Try block uses the resources and the Finally block disposes of them. Because of this, the Using  block guarantees disposal of the resources, no matter how you exit the block. This is true even in the case of an unhandled exception, except for a StackOverflowException." See MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: OK, so looking at that and the related page for try catch finally, it seems that my original code IS closing the response right? Or do i need to add something in Finally - i tried adding response.close() in there but it doesnt work as response is declared in the try block.

Comment: But you can easy declare responese object outside try block and then instantiate it inside try-catch-finally. This will help you use response.close() in Finally block

Comment: Tried that already, i get: NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Very confusing.